# How many 4-digit integers greater than zero have 3 or 6 as their third digit and 3 as their first digit?

Tags: combinatorics

Questions like these are very common on PSAT and SAT tests, and I can never figure it out within a suitable amount of time. Is there an easier way to work through these kinds of problems without having to spend tedious amounts of time?

Comment: Two choices for third digit, and for each choice $10$ choices for second and for each $10$ choices for fourth, total $(2)(10)(10)$.

Comment: I see, so a simple way of solving these is to take the number of choices you have for each digit (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.) and multiply them together, and if they don't place a restriction on one place, it's all 10. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

For the first digit, there is only one choice (which is 3), for the second digit, there are 10 choices (0,1,2,...,9), for the third digit, there are 2 choices (3,6) and for the fourth digit, there are 10 choices (0,1,2,...,9).
Therefore, total number of possibilities = 1*10*2*10=200